# SoftLayer OS Template usage with Softlayer Service API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to [take or apply Softlayer OS image templates](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/introduction-image-templates) with the Services API?

I intend to use the python libraries to do both of these operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to take an OS image template:

```
"""
Create image template.

The script creates a standard image template, it makes
a call to the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createArchiveTransaction method
sending the IDs of the disks in the request.
For more information please see below.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createArchiveTransaction
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The virtual guest ID you want to create a template
virtualGuestId = 13925819
# The name of the image template
groupName = 'my image name'
# An optional note for the image template
note = 'an optional note'

"""
Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device object
containing the disks you want to the image.
In this case we are going take an image template of 2 disks
from the virtual machine.
Make sure the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device is not SWAP. 
"""
blockDevices = [
    {
        "id": 18116783,
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device"
    },
    {
        "id": 18116845,
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device"
    }
]

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    # Creating the transaction for the image template
    response = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].createArchiveTransaction(groupName, blockDevices, note, id=virtualGuestId)
    print(response)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to create the image template. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

You can use this script to create a Virtual Guest using an OS image template:

```
"""
Create Virtual Guest using an OS Template.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

templateId = 1348881

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

order = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
    'quantity': 1,
    'virtualGuests': [
        {'hostname': 'test-template', 'domain': 'example.com'}
    ],
    'location': 168642,  # San Jose 1
    'packageId': 46,     # CCI Package
    'prices': [
        {'id': 1640},  # 1 x 2.0 GHz Core
        {'id': 1644},  # 1 GB RAM
        {'id':  905},  # Reboot / Remote Console
        {'id':  272},  # 10 Mbps Public & Private Networks
        {'id':50231},  # 1000 GB Bandwidth
        {'id':   21},  # 1 IP Address
        {'id': 2202},  # 25 GB (SAN)
        {'id': 1685},  # CentOS 5.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)
        {'id':   55},  # Host Ping Monitoring
        {'id':   57},  # Email and Ticket Notifications
        {'id':   58},  # Automated Notification Response
        {'id':  420},  # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
        {'id':  418},  # Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
    ],
    'imageTemplateId': templateId
}

try:
    # Use verifyOrder to make sure your order is correct.
    # Use placeOrder to make an order directly.
    result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(order)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to verify order. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

> UPDATE

To verify that a virtual server can go through the operating system reload process:

```
"""
Verify that a virtual server can go through the operating system reload process.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/verifyReloadOperatingSystem
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Hardware_Server_Configuration

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The virtual guest ID you want to reload.
virtualGuestId = 15535983
# The image id used in the reloading process.
imageTemplateId = 1349311

"""
Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Hardware_Server_Configuration object
containing image id you want to use.
"""
hardwareServerConfig = [
    {
        "imageTemplateId": imageTemplateId
    }
]

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    response = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].verifyReloadOperatingSystem(hardwareServerConfig, id=virtualGuestId)
    print(response)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to verify reload OS. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

To reloads operating system configuration:

```
"""
Reloads current operating system configuration.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Hardware_Server_Configuration

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The virtual guest ID you want to reload.
virtualGuestId = 15535983
# The image id used in the reloading process.
imageTemplateId = 1349311

"""
Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Hardware_Server_Configuration object
containing image id you want to use.
"""
hardwareServerConfig = [
    {
        "imageTemplateId": imageTemplateId
    }
]
#  To proceed with the reload without confirmation, simply pass in 'FORCE' as the token parameter
token = 'FORCE'

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    response = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].reloadOperatingSystem(token, hardwareServerConfig, id=virtualGuestId)
    print(response)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to reload OS. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

This method could help you as well: **SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::reloadCurrentOperatingSystemConfiguration**

Links for further reading:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/verifyReloadOperatingSystem

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem

Comment: Instead of ordering a new Virtual Guest(vm) is it possible to reload an image on an existing Virtual Guest?